# inherited resources: routes with nested resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, inherited-resources

In my routes.rb I have:

```
resources :fire_preventions do
   get 'search_adv', :on => :collection
end
```

How can I use it with inherited resources routes?

search_adv_collection_url doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can execute `rake routes` in comand line. It will print all available paths according to routes.rb

Comment: I know but I want to use inherited resources url helpers with nested resources.

Comment: Please, explain or show your code sample of nested resource. Routes listed above are not nested.

Answer (score 0):

As there is only one route listed,

```
resources :fire_preventions do 
  get 'search_adv', :on => :collection 
end
```

is shorten form for getting rid of the additional block

```
resources :fire_preventions do 
  collection do
    get 'search_adv'
  end
end
```

You should be able to use `search_adv_fire_preventions_path` and `search_adv_fire_preventions_url`.  It's best that you perform `rake routes` to check this.

Comment: search_adv_fire_preventions_url works but I want to use url helpers from inherited resources and search_adv_collection_url doesn't work.

Comment: Have you looked at these [examples](https://github.com/josevalim/inherited_resources)?  Seems the `collection_url` helper is context sensitive.  Also, see this [screencast](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/230-inherited-resources) if you haven't already.